# Give remote access to mysql DB without revealing the password

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I want to give a remote site (owned my someone else) access to the mysql database on my server that is password protected, but I dont want to reveal the actual password to them.

Is it possible to have the mysql access file (with username and pswd) on my server, and they just connect through it, so that their site can access data in my MYSQL db, but I am not actually openely revealing the pswd to them.

Can such access also be give on a read only basis. I just want to make it so they can query the database, but not download the whole database or make changes to it.

Comment: This question should be asked on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 2):

The remote party will need credentials to be able to do anything with your MySQL database.  Even if you were to open up some sort of file share to let them get to the physical files, that still doesn't let them do anything with the files (and it is *not* a good idea to expose the actual files outside of the database server).

Setup a separate user account just for them that provides them with *just* the permissions they need.

You can limit which MySQL databases the are allowed to access, and exactly what they can do in each individual database.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html

Comment: Do note that remote access also needs to be enabled/configured (firewalls and stuff) on your hosting in order to enable/grant a remote party access to your MySQL server